# EOF Error Parsing Manchester Syntax in OWL-API

Tags: owl, owl-api

I have an API that receive a JSON document with classes, properties and axioms of an ontology. The file looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": "myontologyid",
    "outformat": "OWL",
    "ontoclass": ["Person", "Man", "Woman", "Animal", "Rational", "Arm"],
    "ontoaxioms": ["Man subClassOf (Person)", "Person EquivalentTo: (Man OR Woman)", "hasBrother max 2 xsd:integer"],
    "ontoproperties": ["hasPart", "isBrotherOf", "hasBrother"]
 }
```

The ontoaxioms key is an array with all the axioms of the ontology. The values of this array MUST be in Manchester syntax as I will use the `ManchesterOWLSyntaxParser` to parse.

When I try to parse this code, I get the following error on `hasBrother max 2 xsd:integer` axiom:

```
[apache-tomcat-8.5.69-2]: org.semanticweb.owlapi.manchestersyntax.renderer.ParserException: Encountered |EOF| at line 1 column 29. Expected one of:
    SubClassOf:
    or
    and
    DisjointWith:
    EquivalentTo:
```

I believe the Manchester syntax is incorrect. But I couldn't find any reference or documentation of OWL-API which indicates how to use it. Is there some?

Below is part of my code which tries to parse the axioms:

```
ManchesterOWLSyntaxParserImpl parser = (ManchesterOWLSyntaxParserImpl) OWLManager.createManchesterParser();
parser.setOWLEntityChecker(entityChecker);

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.axiomas.length(); i++) {
        parser.setStringToParse(this.axiomas.getString(i));
        owlOntology.addAxiom(parser.parseAxiom());
    }           
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.toString());
    return null;
}
```

The questions are:

1. How to solve this EOF error?
2. How to insert correctly Manchester Syntax into OWL-API?
3. Where can I find some documentation on how to use Manchester Syntax to parse ontologies?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the Manchester Syntax spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/).

Comment: Hi Henriette. Although this link isn't what I was expecting, it helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of OWLAPI classes appears correct. The problem with the input that something else is expected to follow, i.e., that's not a full axiom.
Is the intent to say that `hasBrother` can only appear twice for an individual and has integer range?

As it happens, there's a unit test in the OWLAPI contract module that uses this string as input for parsing:

```
    String in = "p max 1 owl:real";
    ManchesterOWLSyntaxParser parser = OWLManager.createManchesterParser();
    parser.setStringToParse(in);
    OWLClassExpression cl = parser.parseClassExpression();
```

The string has the same format as what you're trying to parse, and it gives a class expression, not an axiom - specifically, a qualified max cardinality restriction for a data property. This can be the superclass or the subclass in a subclass axiom, for example, but the rest of the axiom is not present.

Comment: Hi Ignazio. I appreciate your answer. Indeed, the axiom I provided is incorrect as an axiom (maybe not as a class expression). I'm gonna provide a detailed answer explaining my thoughts soon. The link Henriette provided me was crucial to this. The fact, I'm finding the OWL-API documentation very poorly on examples. I'm figuring out how to use by trial and error, so the answer I'm gonna to provide try to solve some of these questions. Thanks anyway! :)